# What is the best way to relocate the vertical drain and the vent from where they are near the outer wall for this bathroom?

Tags: plumbing

So in the picture you have the upper bathroom and the bottom bathroom
I am not sure which one by code goes through the roof, the drain (purple vertical pipe) or the vent (grey pipe)

Right now I am renovating the basement bathroom but the plan is to do the same with the main floor bathroom. On that floor the tub has the supply pipes and the drain in the middle of the room. I would like to later relocate those on the outer wall so the pipes running across the upper bathroom floor will have to move along the outer wall

You can probably figure out what is under the floor in the basement.
The street is south of the picture
There is no framing behind the toilet sit, just insulation and drywall so there is a niche there where I could hide these vertical pipes if there is a way to reroute them that way

```
Here is where I need help and suggestions. What is the best way to run
these pipes at their upper and bottom side (I can conceal eventual
elbows above the floor at the bottom and below the floor at the top in
some low profiles enclosures)
```

More details in this thread [What is the best strategy for this layout if I want/need to remove copper plumbing and move to PEX? (two bathrooms connected by the same supply pipes)](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/200777/what-is-the-best-strategy-for-this-layout-if-i-want-need-to-remove-copper-plumbi/200786?noredirect=1#comment361868_200786and) in this one

Here I am asking about the effective way to do it? what fitting to use and where to place cleaning outlets etc etc Not a plumber sorry if I am not using the best terms for this

[image]
At the bottom of these two pipes there is PVC in the floor for the drain
It looks like this
[image]

Here is a schematic diagram
1,4-toilets
3,5 sinks
2,6 bath tubs/showers
[image]
I am assuming the vent connects to the drain in two points located above the highest P trap on [image]

Comment: is there a crawl space or is that floor concrete?

Comment: the basement bathroom floor is concrete, upstairs if framing 2x8sgoing east west inthe picture

Comment: from my reading of https://wabo.memberclicks.net/assets/pdfs/Plumbing_Venting_Brochure_2018.pdf it looks like you're going to need to interconnect that vent pipe and the drain stack if you want to offset them. (page 19)

Comment: I have added a schematic diagram of what I think this  looks like. I do not understand how the vent connects to all these but I am assuming it has a connection on the vertical drain (3") above the level of point 3 (the upstairs sink) and then another one under the floor. I do not understand the reason for that one...it could have been above the floor

Comment: I am guessing the vent pipe connects to the drain like this https://i.imgur.com/Q7rYojC.png

Comment: it seems that I need to read about wet venting a little bit and read the plumbing code